# MongoDB: Добавить поле всем записям в колекции в утилите MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, запрос, compass

Как добавить новое поле всем записям выбраной колекции в MongoDB Compass?
Где в приложении MongoDB Compass делать запрос на обновление колекции?

---

Фиктивный код для примера:

```
db.media.update({$set : {"new_field1: ""}, {multi:true})
```

Comment: я не нашел такого способа

Comment: @Дмытрык Я тоже не могу найти такой способ хотя в документации сказанно что стандартной версии есть возможность создавать, добовлять, редактировать и удалять.

Comment: Редактировать можно. Только каждый документ по отдельности